# Get data for specific month from MS Access 2016 db

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

Good day, I am struggling with an sql select query from my java application. My application connects with an MS Access database. I would like to retrieve all records logged during a specific month. This is my statement:

```
Select * from tbl q
Join (
Select s.Customer from tbl s
Where Month(s.LogDate) = 1 And Year(s.LogDate) = 2017);
```

Problem is that my resultset returns data logged for both January 2017 and December 2016. I have tried different approaches one of which was to pass an sql date(#date#) but I still get the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You JOIN syntax is not valid.

Comment: Hi Gustav, are you referring to the close paranthesis that I neglected to insert after 2017?

Comment: No - you have no joined field(s).

Comment: Hint: The simplest kind of join has the general form `tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.fldX = tbl2.fldY`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the join or the subquery.  Try

```
Select * from tbl where month(logdate)=1 and year(logdate)=2017
```